# iOS How to flip view/image and preserve scale

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I can flip my view by doing something like this:

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

My problem is if I have scaled the item in the app this code obviously sends it back to its original size and flips it.  How can I maintain the current scale and flip the object?

Comment: Can't you just flip **and then** scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the context's current transformation matrix (CTM), and apply your flipping transform to that matrix.

Comment: Graham do you know any good resources/docs on transforms in iOS?